# Kafka high available feature not work

Tags: apache-kafka

I am trying the quickstart of kafka documentation,link is, https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart. 
I have deploy 3 brokers and create a topic.

```
➜  kafka_2.10-0.10.1.0 bin/kafka-topics.sh --describe --zookeeper 
    localhost:2181 --topic my-replicated-topic
    Topic:my-replicated-topic   PartitionCount:1    ReplicationFactor:3 
    Configs:
    Topic: my-replicated-topic  Partition: 0    Leader: 2   Replicas: 2,0,1 
    Isr: 2,1,0
```

Then I use the "bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic my-replicated-topic"  to test producer.
And use "bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --from-beginning --topic my-replicated-topic to test consumer"
the producer and consumer work well. 
if I kill server 1 or 2, the producer and consumer work properly.

but if I kill server 0, and I type the message in producer terminal, the consumer can't read new messages.
when I kill server 0,the consumer print the log:

```
[2017-06-23 17:29:52,750] WARN Auto offset commit failed for group console-consumer-97540: Offset commit failed with a retriable exception. You should 
retry committing offsets. 
(org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator)
[2017-06-23 17:29:52,974] WARN Auto offset commit failed for group console-
consumer-97540: Offset commit failed with a retriable exception. You should 
retry committing offsets. 
(org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator)
[2017-06-23 17:29:53,085] WARN Auto offset commit failed for group console-
consumer-97540: Offset commit failed with a retriable exception. You should 
retry committing offsets. 
(org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator)
[2017-06-23 17:29:53,195] WARN Auto offset commit failed for group console-
consumer-97540: Offset commit failed with a retriable exception. You should 
retry committing offsets. 
(org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator)
[2017-06-23 17:29:53,302] WARN Auto offset commit failed for group console-
consumer-97540: Offset commit failed with a retriable exception. You should 
retry committing offsets. 
(org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator)
[2017-06-23 17:29:53,409] WARN Auto offset commit failed for group console-
consumer-97540: Offset commit failed with a retriable exception. You should 
retry committing offsets. 
(org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator)
```

then I restart the server 0,the consumer print the message and some warn logs:

```
hhhh
hello
[2017-06-23 17:32:32,795] WARN Auto offset commit failed for group console-
consumer-97540: Offset commit failed with a retriable exception. You should 
retry committing offsets. 
(org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator)
[2017-06-23 17:32:32,902] WARN Auto offset commit failed for group console-
consumer-97540: Offset commit failed with a retriable exception. You should 
retry committing offsets. 
(org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator)
```

This confused me.Why server 0 is so special, and the server 0 is not the leader.

And i noticed that server log printed by server 0 has much information as below:

```
[2017-06-23 17:32:33,640] INFO [Group Metadata Manager on Broker 0]: Finished 
loading offsets from [__consumer_offsets,23] in 38 milliseconds. 
(kafka.coordinator.GroupMetadataManager)
[2017-06-23 17:32:33,641] INFO [Group Metadata Manager on Broker 0]: Loading 
offsets and group metadata from [__consumer_offsets,26] 
(kafka.coordinator.GroupMetadataManager)
[2017-06-23 17:32:33,646] INFO [Group Metadata Manager on Broker 0]: Finished 
loading offsets from [__consumer_offsets,26] in 4 milliseconds. 
(kafka.coordinator.GroupMetadataManager)
[2017-06-23 17:32:33,646] INFO [Group Metadata Manager on Broker 0]: Loading 
offsets and group metadata from [__consumer_offsets,29] 
(kafka.coordinator.GroupMetadataManager)
```

but server1 and serve2 log don't have that content.

can somebody explains it for me ,thanks very much!

Solved:
 The replication factor on the _consumer-offsets topic is the root cause. It's an issue: issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-3959

Answer (score 1, accepted):

kafka-console-producer defaults to acks = 1 so that's not fault tolerant at all. Add the flag or config parameter to set acks = all and if your topic and the _consumer-offsets topic were both created with replication factor of 3 your test will work.

Comment: replication factor is a parameter which is set when topic is created.Producer need not set this parameter.

Comment: So sorry I mean acks. Console-producer defaults to acks =  1 which also does not guarantee at least once delivery. When you publish you should specify acks = all to guarantee that all three replicas get the data (assuming the topic was created with replication factor of 3 which I think you are saying it true). Editing my answer to show asks=all and replication factor = 3 are required

Comment: if I only start server1 and server 2 after all 3 servers is shut down, then I create a new topic has replica factor 2, then start the producer and consumer scripts, the consumer still can't read new topic's message unless server 0 is started. The server 0 is so special, that doesn't meet the high available feature. Do I deploy them not correctly?

Comment: Are you putting all three brokers in your bootstrap server list or are you just using "--bootstrap-server localhost:9092"? If the Kafka broker on server 0 is down and you run this command from server 0 then it has no way to get the meta data

Comment: The other thing to check is the replication factor on the _consumer-offsets topic. It may have been created incorrectly when you only had one node and so it's only stored on server 0

Comment: oh! The replication factor on the _consumer-offsets topic is the root cause. It's an issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-3959

Answer (score 1):

The servers share their load for managing Consumer Groups.

Usually each independant consumer has a unique Consumer Group ID and you use the same Group ID when you want to split the consuming process between multiple consumers.

That being said: being the leader broker, for a Kafka server within the cluster, is just for coordination of other brokers. The leader has nothing to do (directly) with the server that is currently managing the Group ID and commits for a specific consumer!

So, whenever you subscribe, you are designated a server which will handle the offset commits for your group and this has nothing to do with leader election.

Shut down that server and you might have issue for your group consumption until the Kafka cluster stabilizes again (reallocates your consumer to move the Group management to other servers or waits for the nodes to respond again... I am not expert enough from there to tell you exactly how the failover happens).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. And I have only one producer and only one consumer in my test. When I close server 0, I wait for a long time.but consumer still can't read messages. And if I only start server1 and server 2 after all 3 servers is shut down, then I create a new topic has replica factor 2, then start the producer and consumer scripts, the consumer still can't read new topic's message unless server 0 is started. The server 0 is so  special,  that doesn't meet the high available feature. Do I deploy them not correctly?

Comment: server 0 is the first broker join in the cluster

Comment: This is from experience, not factual checks I made in Kafka's source code. Usually we apply the following principle: whenever a kafka broker is down or rebuilding, the cluster can become unstable for consumers and failures in both consumptions and production (including commits) can happen.It seems the cluster members know that they are in invalid state. Using idempotence development principles and manual offset commits we just wait for the consumers to end up crashing/hanging and the jobs resume whenever Kafka servers finish making warnings and poorly documented exceptions.

Comment: If  server 0 is down, the cluster won't work well. If I want to delete broker 0 from the cluster forever, what should I do?

Comment: The replication factor on the _consumer-offsets topic is the root cause. It's an issue: issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-3959

Answer (score 0):

Probably, the topic __consumer_offsets has the "Replicas" set to 0.
To confirm this, verify the topic __consumer_offsets:

kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --describe --topic __consumer_offsets

```
Topic: __consumer_offsets   PartitionCount: 50  ReplicationFactor: 1    Configs: compression.type=producer,cleanup.policy=compact,segment.bytes=104857600
Topic: __consumer_offsets   Partition: 0    Leader: 0   Replicas: 0 Isr: 0
Topic: __consumer_offsets   Partition: 1    Leader: 0   Replicas: 0 Isr: 0
Topic: __consumer_offsets   Partition: 2    Leader: 0   Replicas: 0 Isr: 0
Topic: __consumer_offsets   Partition: 3    Leader: 0   Replicas: 0 Isr: 0
Topic: __consumer_offsets   Partition: 4    Leader: 0   Replicas: 0 Isr: 0
...
Topic: __consumer_offsets   Partition: 49   Leader: 0   Replicas: 0 Isr: 0
```

Notice the "Replicas: 0 Isr: 0". This is the reason when you stop the broker 0, the consumer doesn't get the messages anymore.

To correct this, you need to alter the "Replicas" of the topic __consumer_offsets, including the other brokers.

1. Create a json file like this (config/inc-replication-factor-consumer_offsets.json):

```
{"version":1,
 "partitions":[
   {"topic":"__consumer_offsets", "partition":0,  "replicas":[0, 1, 2]},
   {"topic":"__consumer_offsets", "partition":1,  "replicas":[0, 1, 2]},
   {"topic":"__consumer_offsets", "partition":2,  "replicas":[0, 1, 2]},
   {"topic":"__consumer_offsets", "partition":3,  "replicas":[0, 1, 2]},
   {"topic":"__consumer_offsets", "partition":4,  "replicas":[0, 1, 2]},
   {"topic":"__consumer_offsets", "partition":5,  "replicas":[0, 1, 2]},
   {"topic":"__consumer_offsets", "partition":6,  "replicas":[0, 1, 2]},
   {"topic":"__consumer_offsets", "partition":7,  "replicas":[0, 1, 2]},
   {"topic":"__consumer_offsets", "partition":8,  "replicas":[0, 1, 2]},
   {"topic":"__consumer_offsets", "partition":9,  "replicas":[0, 1, 2]},
   {"topic":"__consumer_offsets", "partition":10, "replicas":[0, 1, 2]},
   {"topic":"__consumer_offsets", "partition":11, "replicas":[0, 1, 2]},
   {"topic":"__consumer_offsets", "partition":12, "replicas":[0, 1, 2]},
   {"topic":"__consumer_offsets", "partition":13, "replicas":[0, 1, 2]},
   {"topic":"__consumer_offsets", "partition":14, "replicas":[0, 1, 2]},
   {"topic":"__consumer_offsets", "partition":15, "replicas":[0, 1, 2]},
   {"topic":"__consumer_offsets", "partition":16, "replicas":[0, 1, 2]},
   {"topic":"__consumer_offsets", "partition":17, "replicas":[0, 1, 2]},
   {"topic":"__consumer_offsets", "partition":18, "replicas":[0, 1, 2]},
   {"topic":"__consumer_offsets", "partition":19, "replicas":[0, 1, 2]},
   {"topic":"__consumer_offsets", "partition":20, "replicas":[0, 1, 2]},
   {"topic":"__consumer_offsets", "partition":21, "replicas":[0, 1, 2]},
   {"topic":"__consumer_offsets", "partition":22, "replicas":[0, 1, 2]},
   {"topic":"__consumer_offsets", "partition":23, "replicas":[0, 1, 2]},
   {"topic":"__consumer_offsets", "partition":24, "replicas":[0, 1, 2]},
   {"topic":"__consumer_offsets", "partition":25, "replicas":[0, 1, 2]},
   {"topic":"__consumer_offsets", "partition":26, "replicas":[0, 1, 2]},
   {"topic":"__consumer_offsets", "partition":27, "replicas":[0, 1, 2]},
   {"topic":"__consumer_offsets", "partition":28, "replicas":[0, 1, 2]},
   {"topic":"__consumer_offsets", "partition":29, "replicas":[0, 1, 2]},
   {"topic":"__consumer_offsets", "partition":30, "replicas":[0, 1, 2]},
   {"topic":"__consumer_offsets", "partition":31, "replicas":[0, 1, 2]},
   {"topic":"__consumer_offsets", "partition":32, "replicas":[0, 1, 2]},
   {"topic":"__consumer_offsets", "partition":33, "replicas":[0, 1, 2]},
   {"topic":"__consumer_offsets", "partition":34, "replicas":[0, 1, 2]},
   {"topic":"__consumer_offsets", "partition":35, "replicas":[0, 1, 2]},
   {"topic":"__consumer_offsets", "partition":36, "replicas":[0, 1, 2]},
   {"topic":"__consumer_offsets", "partition":37, "replicas":[0, 1, 2]},
   {"topic":"__consumer_offsets", "partition":38, "replicas":[0, 1, 2]},
   {"topic":"__consumer_offsets", "partition":39, "replicas":[0, 1, 2]},
   {"topic":"__consumer_offsets", "partition":40, "replicas":[0, 1, 2]},
   {"topic":"__consumer_offsets", "partition":41, "replicas":[0, 1, 2]},
   {"topic":"__consumer_offsets", "partition":42, "replicas":[0, 1, 2]},
   {"topic":"__consumer_offsets", "partition":43, "replicas":[0, 1, 2]},
   {"topic":"__consumer_offsets", "partition":44, "replicas":[0, 1, 2]},
   {"topic":"__consumer_offsets", "partition":45, "replicas":[0, 1, 2]},
   {"topic":"__consumer_offsets", "partition":46, "replicas":[0, 1, 2]},
   {"topic":"__consumer_offsets", "partition":47, "replicas":[0, 1, 2]},
   {"topic":"__consumer_offsets", "partition":48, "replicas":[0, 1, 2]},
   {"topic":"__consumer_offsets", "partition":49, "replicas":[0, 1, 2]}
 ]
}
```

2. Execute the following command:

kafka-reassign-partitions.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --zookeeper localhost:2181 --reassignment-json-file ../config/inc-replication-factor-consumer_offsets.json --execute

3. Confirm the "Replicas":

kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --describe --topic __consumer_offsets

```
Topic: __consumer_offsets   PartitionCount: 50  ReplicationFactor: 3    Configs: compression.type=producer,cleanup.policy=compact,segment.bytes=104857600
Topic: __consumer_offsets   Partition: 0    Leader: 0   Replicas: 0,1,2 Isr: 0,2,1
Topic: __consumer_offsets   Partition: 1    Leader: 0   Replicas: 0,1,2 Isr: 0,2,1
Topic: __consumer_offsets   Partition: 2    Leader: 0   Replicas: 0,1,2 Isr: 0,2,1
Topic: __consumer_offsets   Partition: 3    Leader: 0   Replicas: 0,1,2 Isr: 0,2,1
...
Topic: __consumer_offsets   Partition: 49   Leader: 0   Replicas: 0,1,2 Isr: 0,2,1
```

4. Now you can stop only the broker 0, produce some messages and see the result on the consumer.